# Keras SeparableConv2D simple example?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I've read a lot of good stuff about Separable Convolution it and I'm trying to put it into practice.

I picked up dataset 64x64 pics with 11599 train and 2891 for test with 200 labels.

```
i = inp

i = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 4)(i)
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)
i = MaxPooling2D(2)(i)    
i = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 4)(i)    
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)
i = MaxPooling2D(2)(i)    
i = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 4)(i)
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)
i = MaxPooling2D(2)(i)
i = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 4)(i)
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)

i = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(i)

i = Dense(len(labels), activation = 'softmax')(i)
```

this model gave me 0.75 test and 0.89 train accuracy

Then I decided to try Separable Convolution but I couldn't find simple examples. In Keras repository it used in xception, but it's too difficult for me.

```
i = inp

i = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 4)(i)
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)
i = MaxPooling2D(2)(i)

i = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 4)(i)    
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)
i = MaxPooling2D(2)(i)

i = SeparableConv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = 4, strides = 1)(i)
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)
i = SeparableConv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = 4, strides = 1)(i)
i = BatchNormalization()(i)
i = LeakyReLU()(i)

i = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(i)

i = Dense(len(labels), activation = 'softmax')(i)

m = Model(inp, i)
```

With this model, I achieved about the same results.
I think im doing wrong something.

Answer (score 3):

Well - it's hard to say, but I think that you misunderstood the main purpose of using `SeparableConvolution`. The decomposition introduced was used mainly for two reasons:

- to reduce the number of parameters and speed up computations,
- reduce overfitting (by simplifying network architecture).

So - in your case, you might check if this happened by:

- comparing the time of training/inference and number of parameters,
- checking if overfitting is less.

All of these might be obtained by network logs and `model.summary()` function.

Comment: Yes, I have fewer parameters, but more train time (15 mins vs 20).